# Impact on pipeline agents when you change organisation URL in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'd like to rename my organisation URL in Azure Devops. The [support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/rename-organization?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav) [articles](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2793597/things-to-do-before-and-after-you-rename-the-url-of-your-team-foundati) describe the impact, and what to do. But they don't mention any impact on the Azure Pipelines agent.

However, when I look at the `.agent` config file, there's a `serverUrl` property that points to the specific organisation URL.

So - if I rename my organisation URL, will it impact my agents? Do I need to reconfigure them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will impact your agents.

Currently, they configure to the first URL, when you change the URL they still configure to the old one and they can't connect, you must re-configure them to the new URL.

I just tested it:

[image]

The last line is when I renamed my organization, I checked also in the pool, the agent is offline. If I try to run a build I got this error:

[image]