# Migrating from myorg.visualstudio.com to dev.azure.com/myorg

Tags: azure-devops

My organization still uses the "old" url when interacting with Azure DevOps: myorg.visualstudio.com.
The options to switch over to the new url has been available for some time in organization settings, but we've not made the move yet.
[image]

Today, for the first time, I saw a warning advertising that a feature was only available on the new Url

[image]

So I'm thinking it's about time I start moving my organization and push our users to use the new url.
I can see that both the old and new url can be used to access Azure DevOps in a browser, and according to this question: [Switch existing organizations to use the new domain name URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58122693/switch-existing-organizations-to-use-the-new-domain-name-url), both will continue to works once I flip the switch.

For our non-developer users that only uses the web interface of Azure DevOps (Task management, wiki, etc) this is going to be easy as they can slowly adjust over time to use the new Url.

But I have some concerns for our developers, that I haven't been able to find any answers to.
1. What about Git remote urls?
2. What about Build Agents' connection to Azure DevOps?

I've tested cloning from git, replacing myorg.visualstudio.com with dev.azure.com/myorg in the url, which failed.
I've not yet tested connecting a build agent to Azure DevOps using the new url.

Will I be able to slowly migrate those two things aswell?
Or will I have to have set a date to flip the switch, and instruct our developers to ensure no builds are running, backup local uncommited code changes, and make the appropiate changes at that time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. What about Git remote urls?

According to [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/vsts-name-change-in-azure-devops-effects-on-git-re),  *the name change from VSTS to Azure DevOps changed the base URL from accountname.visualstudio.com to dev.azure.com/accountname, and this broke the build.*, the change of organization would affect the Git remote commands.

About the solution mentioned in the article and your test, what about replace `myorg.visualstudio.com` with `myorg:{token}/dev.azure.com` or `{token}@dev.azure.com/myorg`?

> 2. What about Build Agents' connection to Azure DevOps?

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53099839/impact-on-pipeline-agents-when-you-change-organisation-url-in-azure-devops), the conenction will be lost: *when you change the URL they still configure to the old one and they can't connect, you must re-configure them to the new URL.*